# Playing a Youtube Video from a Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to write a Discord bot in JavaScript, and my next goal is to get it to play audio from YouTube. I'm having trouble finding tutorials online since most of them are in Python. Does anyone know how to make a Discord bot play music from Youtube?